# Operation of $O_2$ on the plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently reading through M. Artin's Algebra 2.ed. In chapter 6, remarks similar to the following are often made with little explanation:

"Unless an origin is chosen, the orthogonal group $O_2$ doesn't operate on the plane $P$."

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Do you know how $O_2$ acts on the plane with an origin chosen? (i.e., is your question why a choice of origin is necessary?)

Comment: @AlexBecker I do understand how it acts once an origin is chosen. It seems to me intuitively, however, that $O_2$ does act on the plane regardless of whether there is an origin, except that without an origin there is no way to properly describe this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the plane as a two-dimensional vector space, then $O_2$ acts on the plane by matrix multiplication in the obvious way.

If I just hand you an affine space which is isomorphic (as an affine space) to the plane, though, there's no natural choice of a vector space structure on it, so there's no natural action of $O_2$ on it.  If you pick a  point to be the origin, this completely determines a unique vector space structure compatible with the affine structure and now you have an action of $O_2$, but any such choice is just as good as any other and they give you different actions.

So, more precisely, there are infinitely many actions of $O_2$ on a plane with no fixed origin, none of which are natural, in contrast to the natural action of $O_2$ on a plane with a fixed origin given by matrix multiplication.

(Natural is a technical term essentially meaning that you can specify an object uniquely.  A precise definition is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation)

Comment: If choosing different origins gives you different actions, does this not imply that $O_2$ "alters" the underlying space in some manner that appears different depending on how the origin is chosen?

Comment: Ah, yes, what you have said after "So, more precisely," is in essence what I was thinking to be true. This clears up the issue, thanks.

Comment: Once you get into more advanced algebra courses, naturality becomes a major theme, to the point where you'll often sort of throw naturality assumptions in without even realizing that you're doing it.  That's essentially what's going on here.